# Creating a new tag before you have enough rep

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, taxonomist-badge

I noticed today that I can add a tag to my "favorite tag" list that does not yet exist.  I then went to ask a question using that tag and was told I do not yet have enough rep to create new tags.

So my question is this:

If someone else creates that same tag, do I get any credit for coming up with it first (as shown by the fact that I listed it in my favorite tag list), or is the fact that it appears in my favorite list, even though it doesn't yet exist, just a placeholder for when it does.

Comment: You can always flag the question and ask a mod to create the tag for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding tags to your favourites list doesn't create them, so if the tag were to enter usage you would *not* be credited, but they would start to be flagged as favourites.

Since favourites can be used with wildcards (with `*`) and tags that don't exist, I presume that they work more as a text search than a direct link to a tag.

Comment: I didn't know I could use wildcards in my fav tags.  Good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: @lazy, I use them all the time for flagging an entire series of games as a favourite on [Gaming.SE]; it can come in rather handy. :)

Comment: You get the answer for heads up about wildcard bonus.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new tag but you don't have enough reputation, you can add a comment in which you ask for some other user to add the tag. But you don't get the credit (taxonomist badge).

But remember, tags are primarily to select questions with the same subject. The badge is not such a big deal. Besides there are lots of other badges that can be aquired (even at rep < 1500).

Comment: Not a big deal.... but it's still kind of fun... that's why stackoverflow is so popular.  It's the tags and rep!